# JavaScript .reduce, previousValue is always undefined

Tags: javascript

I am curious as to why previousValue is always undefined in the following code when using .reduce on an array:

Code:

```
[2,2,2,3,4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
    console.log("Previous Value: " + previousValue);
    console.log("Current Value: " + currentValue);
},0)
```

Output:

```
Previous Value: 0 (index):
Current Value: 2 (index):
Previous Value: undefined (index):
Current Value: 2 (index):
Previous Value: undefined (index):
Current Value: 2 (index):
Previous Value: undefined (index):
Current Value: 3 (index):24
Previous Value: undefined (index):23
Current Value: 4
```

A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LzpxE/

Comment: You need to return something from the `function`. This will be the value of `previousValue` on the next iteration.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to return a value in order to use `reduce` correctly. The returned value will be used in the next step.

Like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
     return previousValue + currentValue;
});
// returns 10 in total, because
// 0 + 1 = 1 -> 1 + 2 = 3 -> 3 + 3 = 6 -> 6 + 4 = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you are not returning any value from previous iteration of reduce() and he think that his previous value is undefined.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce()` function has its callback. The **value** returned in the callback is the `previousValue` argument presented in the function signature.

It is not the previous index in the array. If you want `previousValue` to display the previous element in the array, you can return the current value in the callback:

```js
[12, 23, 34, 45, 56].reduce((previous, current, index, array) => { return current })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).